# Dynamic stacked column in CanvasJS

Tags: javascript, json, canvasjs

How can I create a stacked column chart with dynamic data?

For example, I have an external JSON object like:

```
[
  {
    id : ‘ID123’,
    occurrences: [5,6,8],
    description: ["Hours spent working", "Hours spent skiing", "Hours spent studying"]
  },
  {
    id : ‘ID456’,
    occurrences: [7,2,12],
    description: ["Hours spent working", "Hours spent skiing", "Hours spent studying"]
  }
]
```

How do I make it so there would be two stacked columns using the id as the label and the array of occurrences is used to build the stacked column on top of each label?

Edit:
Added representation of how graph should look

[image: Representation of graph]

Comment: how is the occurrences data supposed to be used for creating columns? could you please be a little more specific? you should probably give an example of what you have tried already or give some visual aid as to  what you are wanting.

Comment: alternatively if you do not know how to do something there are most likely frameworks or plugins to do what you are wanting like https://www.chartjs.org/

Comment: Okay I have updated my original question to be more specific. The elements in the occurrences array are mapped to the strings in the description array. The stacked column will be split into three sections where the 0th element in the array (bottom section of chart) is linked to the 0th element in the description array. I will also add a crude representation of this in to the question.

Comment: I've added the graph now @nicholaslabrecque

Comment: If I helped you you can show thanks by confirming my answer helped you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using chart.js for this as it will be much easier than building it out yourself. Here is a example using the data you provided.

```js
var barChartData = {
   labels: ['ID123', 'ID456'],
   datasets: [{
    label: 'Hours spent working',
    backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
    data: [
     5,
     7
    ]
   }, {
    label: 'Hours spent skiing',
    backgroundColor: '#00FF00',
    data: [
     6,
     2
    ]
   }, {
    label: 'Hours spent studying',
    backgroundColor: '#0000FF',
    data: [
     8,
     12,
    ]
   }]

  };
  window.onload = function() {
   var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
   window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: barChartData,
    options: {
     title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked'
     },
     tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false
     },
     responsive: true,
     scales: {
      xAxes: [{
       stacked: true,
      }],
      yAxes: [{
       stacked: true
      }]
     }
    }
   });
  };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```